# How to convert a map into a collection without the keys

Tags: clojure

I have a map like this:

```
{1 [1 4 7], 2 [2 5 8], 0 [3 6 9]}
```

I want to write a function that returns this:

```
[[1 4 7] [2 5 8] [3 6 9]]
```

As a side note, I'm getting the map by doing this:

```
(group-by #(mod % 3) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])
```

If anyone has a shortcut for going from a vector like this: `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` to the second one shown above, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does order matter? `vals` is takes a map, and returns a sequence of the values. But order is not defined for a map, so the order of the values sequence returned is arbitrary.

```
> (vals {1 [1 4 7], 2 [2 5 8], 0 [3 6 9]})
([3 6 9] [1 4 7] [2 5 8])
```

Sorted:

```
> (sort (vals {1 [1 4 7], 2 [2 5 8], 0 [3 6 9]}))
([1 4 7] [2 5 8] [3 6 9])
```

Comment: That works! Order doesn't matter for my current problem. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 3):

As to your other question: `(partition 3 v)` creates a matrix, and `(apply map vector m)` is an idiom to transpose a matrix m (how does it work? Exercise for the reader or google it). So:

```
> (apply map vector (partition 3 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]))
([1 4 7] [2 5 8] [3 6 9])
```

There are other ways of course. For example, with destructuring:

```
> (let [{ a 0 b 1 c 2 } (group-by #(mod % 3) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])] [b c a])
[[1 4 7] [2 5 8] [3 6 9]]
```